# Disable plugin in react-chartjs2?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I'm trying to dynamically enable and disable plugins rendered a react-chartjs-2 component.

The plugins that should be rendered are passed to the component like this:

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { my_plugin_t} from '../types/all_types'
import { Chart as ChartJS, ChartType,  registerables, ChartOptions } from 'chart.js';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';

const MyPlot = ({signals, plugin_list}: { signals: signal_t[], plugin_list: any[]}) => {

    ChartJS.register(...registerables);
    // ... chart setup of data and options...
   
    return(
        <>
        <Line ref={chartRef} data={data} options={options} plugins={plugin_list} />
        </>
    )
}
```

When the plugin_list includes the plugins that need to be drawn in the first rendering of the component it shows up fine. When I leave it empty, it does not show up.
However, changing `plugin_list` does not toggle whether the plugin is enabled or disabled.

Is there a way to dynamically add or remove plugins to the `Line` component?